# MixPanel - Hide events and properties of a user

Tags: android, mixpanel

In Mixpanel project settings, there is an option to hide events and properties of an event.

[image: Hide events and properties]

I am able to unset people properties using

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance (context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.getPeople().unset(propertiesJson);
```

But I need to hide events and properties using [Mixpanel Android API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android).

Answer (score 0):

As their [manual article](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/can-i-delete-or-hide-events-and-properties-from-my-project) says, events data is immutable in Mixpanel.

The UI you mentioned for hiding events indeed just *hides* all events with a specific name - it does not change the underlying events data.

The API call you mention unsets a specific property on a user profile. This is possible, as profiles (as opposed to events) are mutable.

Hence, I believe a programmatic way to remove or hide events does not exist.